# Copy many columns from one data.frame to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data.frame named `test` with 500 columns. I need to create the data.frame `test1` with 7 columns, from `test` (their number is 1,2, 52, 121, 123, 344, 401 etc.)
How can I do that easily? (I mean shortly )

Answer (score 12):

A short example.  Take columns 1,3 of a small data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), c=c(7,8,9),d=c(2,3,4))
d[,c(1,3)]

  a c
1 1 7
2 2 8
3 3 9
```